# Short story where humans cannot innovate in a seniority-driven world, and a general defects to the alien side

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was a short story from a sci-fi magazine where, during a war between humans and aliens, a human general goes to the alien side due to humanity's inability to innovate in a pure seniority-driven world. By wiping planets, he creates enough fear for humanity to innovate.

Comment: Please add any further details you can remember, especially in what year (or range of years) you read this and the language / country of the magazine.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be [The Highest Treason by Randall Garrett](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/24302) (readable on that Project Gutenberg  page), mentioned previously on Stackexchange [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102456/seeking-short-story-collection) as a partial answer to another question.

Comment: Accepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151886/story-about-a-guy-who-intentionally-becomes-ultimate-bad-guy-to-trigger-societal/151930#151930